# SQL Query to get data from all databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi wondering if someone can assist me with this query. I am trying to display how many submissions I have from all my databases in the server from a table. The goal is to display all but also how many per database. The following query allows me to view per database but I want to get the info from all of them in one shot for the purpose of time.

```
SELECT *
FROM myforms
WHERE datetime between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-23'
```

Server Specs: 
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqli

Example of the goal:

Lets say these are the database

```
db_site1
db_site2
db_site3
```

In each one has a table called myforms with a field called datefield.

Want to get the following information with one query.

```
db_site1 - 5 (this being number of submissions from jan 1, 2017 to current date)
db_site2 - 50
db_site3 - 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union to collect result from diff-diff tables in single query.

```
(SELECT * FROM db_site1.myforms WHERE datetime between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-23')
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM db_site2.myforms WHERE datetime between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-23')
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM db_site3.myforms WHERE datetime between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-23')
```

Note:- For this query your db user must have access to all 3 databases. **Union All** will remove duplicate from result. If you need duplicate result then use **union**.

Comment: This is a good alternative but i have 35 total databases. Any chance you have something easier :)

Comment: @James, either create a view or stored procedure in one of database and then access using single query.

Comment: @James or if you are afraid of writing query, can use a loop to create query